# How to hide a hovering menu after click on Link in react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a problem with react-router-dom.

***I had the same menu for mobile and desktop***

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9lTZ.png

In mobile mode I can handle the menu close and open with state but in desktop mode. I want to close the hovered menu after user click on `<Link />` component.

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';

class Item extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <li>
            <NavLink replace to={'/categories/' + this.props.slug}>{this.props.name}</NavLink>
            { this.props.children }
        </li>
    }
}

class MainNav extends React.Component {

    list = (data) => {
        const children = (items) => {
            if (items && items.length) {
                return <ul>{ this.list(items) }</ul>
            }
        }
        return data.map((node, index) => {
            return <Item key={ node.id } slug={node.slug} name={ node.name }>
                { children(node.children) }
            </Item>
        });
    }

    render() {
        return <ul className="nav">
            { this.list(this.props.categories) }
        </ul>

    }
}

export default MainNav;
```

Assume that I just want to fix for desktop version only. How to do that!

Thank you

Comment: Please share the code you currently have on this

Answer (score 0):

Checking if the device is mobile or desktop is not [trivial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top), but you could add this to property to `Link` element:

```js
onClick={ window.orientation > -1 ? null : YourCloseMenuSetter }
```

This will do nothing `null` if the device is a mobile on (has orientation).
If it is not a mobile device it will run the function that closes the menu, so called YourCloseMenuSetter.

Comment: Thank yuri! you do not understand my question. I mean I cannot close the menu on desktop when clicking on menu item because It is handled by css hover property.